# Помогите решить задачу на питонее

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я решаю задачу на Степике, но у меня вылазит ошибка
суть задачи в том, чтобы вычислить ИМТ и узнать массу (жирный или нет).

```
# put your python code here
a = float(input());
b = float(input());
result = a / b*b

if result < 18.5 and result > 25:
    print('Оптимальная масса')
if result > 18.5:
    print('Недостаточная масса')
elif result > 25:
    print('Избыточная масса')
```

но этот код выводит ошибку

> ```
> Failed test #1 of 10. Wrong answer
>
> This is a sample test from the problem statement:
>
> Test input:
> 65
> 1.75
> Correct output:
> Оптимальная масса
>
> Your code output:
> Недостаточная масса
> ```

Comment: Так разберитесь с условиями внутри `if`, они же явно неверные. У вас даже тест на котором не проходит есть...

Comment: И формула неправильная

Answer (score 1):

В вашем коде несколько небольших ошибок:

1. ```
   a / b*b
   ```

   Это значит делить `а` на `b` и затем результат (обратно) умножить на `b`.
   Таким образом вы просто получите `a`.

   Нужно применить скобки:

   ```
   a / (b * b)
   ```
2. ```
   if result < 18.5 and result > 25:
   ```

   Не может быть результат *меньшим* чем 18.5 и **одновременно** *большим* чем 25.

   Вы наверно хотели

   ```
   if result > 18.5 and result < 25:
   ```

   что возможно написать более наглядно (по-математически) как

   ```
   if 18.5 < result < 25:
   ```

   Но по всей вероятности надо включить и границы:

   ```
   if 18.5 <= result <= 25:
   ```
3. ```
   if result > 18.5:
       print('Недостаточная масса')
   ```

   Когда масса **недостаточная**, то результат должен быть не больше, а **меньше**:

   ```
   if result < 18.5:
       print('Недостаточная масса')
   ```
4. ```
   elif result > 25:
      print('Избыточная масса')
   ```

   Это правильно, но так как в предыдущих двух условиях вы применили `if`, более красиво бы было вместо `elif` тоже применить `if`:

   ```
   if result > 25:
      print('Избыточная масса')
   ```

Или вообще применить констукцию `if` -  `elif` - `else`:

```
if 18.5 <= result <= 25:
    print('Оптимальная масса')
elif result < 18.5:
    print('Недостаточная масса')
else:
    print('Избыточная масса')
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Добавьте скобки в result. Сейчас это не имеет значения, но хорошей практикой является явное указание знаменателя.
2. b*b можно написать, но лучше b**2
3. Разберитесь с условиями. Там у вас каша

Comment: `b*b можно написать, но лучше b**2` - добавьте объяснение, почему так стоит делать. `Разберитесь с условиями. Там у вас каша` - укажите что именно не так в условиях, из вашего текста непонятно что не так.

Answer (score -1):

```
a = float(input())
b = float(input())
result = a / b*b

if result > 18.5 and result < 25:
    print('Оптимальная масса')
elif result < 18.5:
    print('Недостаточная масса')
elif result > 25:
    print('Избыточная масса')
```

Попробуй вот так.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).